# Method chaining to communicate between GUI parts in a MVC in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller

I am creating a Java Desktop GUI application using the MVC pattern. For the sake of simplicity, I have divided in GUI application into different panels ([Scheme of the GUI application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmrJr.png)) so that each class takes care of something specific. Now, when I am in the Controller part and want to display something in the DRAW PANEL, I have a method chaining. I mean I am calling several methods in a row:

```
view.getRightPanel().getDrawPanel().appendText(model.getResults());
```

I am wondering whether or not I am making a mistake somewhere. Is it normal to do so, or should I change my code to make it more efficient and elegant? 
Any information is welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making a mistake if you are doing this in the controller.

In the MVC pattern, the controller listens for model changes and updates the view. That is what the controller is supposed to do. Here,

```
view.getRightPanel().getDrawPanel().appendText(model.getResults());
```

I guess you are changing the text in a draw panel in the view that controller is controlling, which is exactly what the controller is supposed to do.

Do be careful not to change update the model directly from the view, or update the view from the model though. That violates MVC.

I also suggest you to create multiple controllers to control different panels on the screen. I think that way it will be more manageable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is it a problem to call several functions in a row? I mean, if I had more panels, I would end up calling 10 or more functions in a row.

Comment: The general rule is that you should keep your code readable. If you think your code becomes unreadable, you should probably start creating new controllers. One controller for each panel. @Anthony